# how to access modifier from a method from same class?

Tags: java

I'm trying to increase `numberOfQuestion` by 1 at any time I call `isOdd()` method as shown below. I got an error said "

> unreachable code

". how I could do it right?!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Geek {

    private String geekName;
    private int numberOfQuestion;

    public Geek (String name) {

        geekName=name;
        numberOfQuestion=0;

    }


    public int getNumberOfQuestion() {
        return numberOfQuestion;

    }

    public boolean isOdd(int num) {

        if(num%2==0) {
            return false;

        }
        else { 
            return true;
        }
         numberOfQuestion++;
    }




}
```

Comment: Put it in a `finally` clause. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Put `numberOfQuestions++` as the first line in method `public boolean isOdd(intNum)`

The message is correct, your line is unreachable since you return from method before incrementing it.

Answer (score 2):

`numberOfQuestion++;` is considered unreacheable code because in either case:

- if `num` is odd, your method returns true and exit the method.
- if `num` is even, your method returns false and exit the method as well.

As you can see there is no way it will be able to reach the line:

```
numberOfQuestion++;
```

Hence, if you want to do something, you need to do it before your method ends:

```
public boolean isOdd(int num) {
    //whatever you want to do here.. such as numberOfQuestion++;
    return (num % 2 != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the increace statement at first line:

```
public boolean isOdd(int num) {
     numberOfQuestion++;    
     if(num%2==0) {
        return false;

     }
     return true;
 }
```

At last line it is unreachable, because you return in `if` and in `else`

Answer (score 0):

After return method closed and numberOfQuestion++ never done.
You need this:

```
public boolean isOdd(int num) {
    numberOfQuestion++;
    if(num%2==0) {
        return false;

    }
    else { 
        return true;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in function 'isOdd', whatever the 'num' may be, the function get returned and the last line,

```
numberOfQuestion++;
```

will never execute, So it's an unreachable code.
just make the code like this,

```
public boolean isOdd(int num) {
numberOfQuestion++;
if(num%2==0) {
    return false;

}
else { 
    return true;
}

}
```